# Adding a navigation controller programmatically for the second VC

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my storyboard, I have setup a navigation controller points to my MainVC, and it works just fine.
And now, I'm trying to add another view called "HelpVC", and I created one in the storyboard. It automatically shows the navigation bar on the top.
(MainVC segues to HelpVC)

However, I did everything else in code.
I had initWithView in the HelpVC which draws out the interface, BUT the navigation bar does not show up, so I can't go back to that previous view controller.

How do I make sure that the navigation bar shows up and works just like other view controllers? (segue back to the last view?)

Comment: see how `pushViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)` works

Comment: can you show your stroryboard screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear from the post, but as I understood, you may want to try:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```